# Multi-thread em Socket Java

Tags: java, socket, multithreading

Não tenho experiencia em Java, então mais uma vez, recorro ao Stack pra me ajudar, possuo um código básico de um servidor que recebe uma mensagem de um cliente via socket e o código desse cliente, preciso modificar ambos, pra aceitar conexões de mais clientes.

```
/**
 * Classe Servidor - responsável por criar a conexão e receber as conexões dos clientes.
 * Exibe a informação enviada pelo cliente.
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{     

        //Cria um socket na porta 12345
        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket (12345);
        System.out.println("Porta 12345 aberta!");

        // Aguarda alguém se conectar. A execução do servidor
        // fica bloqueada na chamada do método accept da classe
        // ServerSocket. Quando alguém se conectar ao servidor, o
        // método desbloqueia e retorna com um objeto da classe
        // Socket, que é uma porta da comunicação.

        System.out.print("Aguardando conexão do cliente...");       

        System.out.println("Nova conexao com o cliente " + cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());


        //Recebe a mensagem enviada pelo cliente
        Scanner s = new Scanner(cliente.getInputStream());

        //Exibe mensagem no console
        while(s.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(s.nextLine());
        }

        //Finaliza objetos
        s.close();
        cliente.close();
        servidor.close();
        System.out.println("Fim do Servidor!");
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Cliente extends thread{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException 
    {

        // para se conectar ao servidor, cria-se objeto Socket.
        // O primeiro parâmetro é o IP ou endereço da máquina que
        // se quer conectar e o segundo é a porta da aplicação.
        // Neste caso, usa-se o IP da máquina local (127.0.0.1)
        // e a porta da aplicação ServidorDeEco (12345).

        Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);
        System.out.println("O cliente conectou ao servidor");

        //Prepara para leitura do teclado
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Cria  objeto para enviar a mensagem ao servidor
        PrintStream saida = new PrintStream(cliente.getOutputStream());

        //Envia mensagem ao servidor
        while(teclado.hasNextLine())
        {
            saida.println(teclado.nextLine());          
        }

        saida.close();
        teclado.close();
        cliente.close();
        System.out.println("Fim do cliente!");
    }
}
```

Será que alguém poderia me dar uma ideia? To realmente perdido com esses exercícios.

Comment: Você poderia postar o código da classe `TratamentoClass`?

Comment: Então @casscarraro, na verdade esse TratamentoClass nem tem no código que eu tenho que alterar, até editei o código na pergunta, o código que tenho é esse ai.Tem que ser feito baseado nele.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, para que você possa aceitar mais conexões de clientes no seu servidor, uma solução é a adaptação do seu servidor para trabalhar com `Multithread`.

O conceito de `Multithread`, falando simplificadamente, torna possível a execução de várias tarefas de uma mesma aplicação ao mesmo tempo.

Voltando ao seu problema, a solução pode ser a seguinte, você pode criar seu servidor como uma `Thread` e instanciá-lo para cada novo cliente, persistindo o socket do cliente em uma variável para poder ser gerenciado posteriormente.

Classe do Servidor:

```
public class Server implements Runnable{
    public Socket cliente;

    public Server(Socket cliente){
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException{     

        //Cria um socket na porta 12345
        ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket (12345);
        System.out.println("Porta 12345 aberta!");

        // Aguarda alguém se conectar. A execução do servidor
        // fica bloqueada na chamada do método accept da classe
        // ServerSocket. Quando alguém se conectar ao servidor, o
        // método desbloqueia e retorna com um objeto da classe
        // Socket, que é uma porta da comunicação.
        System.out.println("Aguardando conexão do cliente...");   

        while (true) {
          Socket cliente = servidor.accept();
          // Cria uma thread do servidor para tratar a conexão
          Server tratamento = new Server(cliente);
          Thread t = new Thread(tratamento);
          // Inicia a thread para o cliente conectado
          t.start();
        }
    }

    /* A classe Thread, que foi instancia no servidor, implementa Runnable.
       Então você terá que implementar sua lógica de troca de mensagens dentro deste método 'run'.
    */
    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Nova conexao com o cliente " + this.cliente.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());

        try {
            Scanner s = null;
            s = new Scanner(this.cliente.getInputStream());

            //Exibe mensagem no console
            while(s.hasNextLine()){
                System.out.println(s.nextLine());
            }

            //Finaliza objetos
            s.close();
            this.cliente.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Classe do Cliente:

```
//Prefira implementar a interface Runnable do que extender a classe Thread, pois neste caso utilizaremos apena o método run.
public class Cliente implements Runnable{

    private Socket cliente;

    public Cliente(Socket cliente){
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

        // para se conectar ao servidor, cria-se objeto Socket.
        // O primeiro parâmetro é o IP ou endereço da máquina que
        // se quer conectar e o segundo é a porta da aplicação.
        // Neste caso, usa-se o IP da máquina local (127.0.0.1)
        // e a porta da aplicação ServidorDeEco (12345).
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 12345);

        /*Cria um novo objeto Cliente com a conexão socket para que seja executado em um novo processo.
        Permitindo assim a conexão de vário clientes com o servidor.*/
        Cliente c = new Cliente(socket);
        Thread t = new Thread(c);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            PrintStream saida;
            System.out.println("O cliente conectou ao servidor");

            //Prepara para leitura do teclado
            Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

            //Cria  objeto para enviar a mensagem ao servidor
            saida = new PrintStream(this.cliente.getOutputStream());

            //Envia mensagem ao servidor
            while(teclado.hasNextLine()){
                saida.println(teclado.nextLine());          
            }

            saida.close();
            teclado.close();
            this.cliente.close();
            System.out.println("Fim do cliente!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta solução funciona perfeitamente? Podem me explicar o que é a variável tratamento? Isto dá para fazer estabelecer contacto num chat de mensagens de texto (Como fazemos agora para não imprimir mensagens na consola mas sim para que uma aplicação desse género de)??